# Summary of descriptive data

Tags: r, mean, median, summary, panel-data

i got a panel data set. I am analysing name changes of mutual funds. I created 6m prior & 6m past name-change Mean & Median values for various variables.

I want to summarise the results like this just without the t-test:
[image]

I tried stargazer. But if i insert more than 2 DFs i get an error: Error in if (is.na(s)) { : the condition has length > 1. And it doesn't look anything close to the above anyways.

My data is stored / created as follows:

```
library(readxl)
New_R_done <- read_excel("New_R done.xlsx")
View(New_R_done)

library(tidyverse)
library(plm)
descr <- pdata.frame(New_R_done, index=c("ISIN", "Date"))
str(descr)
length(levels(as.factor(descr$Dummy)))
length(levels(as.factor(descr$ISIN)))
descr <- descr %>% na.omit()
View(descr)
#Return 
descr$Returns <- ifelse(descr$Returns=="n.a", 0, descr$Returns)
descr$Returns <- as.numeric(descr$Returns)

#Flows
descr$Flows <- ifelse(descr$Flows=="n.a", 0, descr$Flows)
descr$Flows <- as.numeric(descr$Flows)

#TNA
descr$TNA <- ifelse(descr$TNA=="n.a", 0, descr$TNA)
descr$TNA <- as.numeric(descr$TNA)

name_change <- ifelse(descr$Dummy==1 & lag(descr$Dummy, 1)==0, 1, 0)

# Median Return 
lags <- plm::lag(descr$Returns, 1:6)
lag_median <- apply(lags, 1, median)
leads <- plm::lead(descr$Returns, 1:6)
lead_median <- apply(leads, 1, median)
d <- data.frame(name_change, lag_median, lead_median)
d[d$name_change==1,]

# Median Flows
lags_flow <- plm::lag(descr$Flows, 1:6)
lag_median_flow <- apply(lags_flow, 1, median)
leads_flow <- plm::lead(descr$Flows, 1:6)
lead_median_flow <- apply(leads_flow, 1, median)
d_flow <- data.frame(name_change, lag_median_flow, lead_median_flow)
d_flow[d_flow$name_change==1,]

#Median TNA
lags_TNA <- plm::lag(descr$TNA, 1:6)
lag_median_TNA <- apply(lags_TNA, 1, median)
leads_TNA <- plm::lead(descr$TNA, 1:6)
lead_median_TNA <- apply(leads_TNA, 1, median)
d_TNA <- data.frame(name_change, lag_median_TNA, lead_median_TNA)
d_TNA[d_TNA$name_change==1,]


# Mean Return 
lag_mean <- apply(lags, 1, mean)
lead_mean <- apply(leads, 1, mean)
d_m <- data.frame(name_change, lag_mean, lead_mean)
d_m[d_m$name_change==1,]

# Mean Flows 
lag_mean_flow <- apply(lags_flow, 1, mean)
lead_mean_flow <- apply(leads_flow, 1, mean)
d_flow_mean <- data.frame(name_change, lag_mean_flow, lead_mean_flow)
d_flow_mean[d_flow_mean$name_change==1,]

# Mean TNA 
lag_mean_tna <- apply(lags_TNA, 1, mean)
lead_mean_tna <- apply(leads_TNA, 1, mean)
d_tna_mean <- data.frame(name_change, lag_mean_tna, lead_mean_tna)
d_tna_mean[d_tna_mean$name_change==1,]

# Return Median +6 -6 
makeRETURN <- d[d$name_change==1,]
mean(makeRETURN$lag_median) 
mean(makeRETURN$lead_median, na.rm = TRUE)

# Flow Median +6 -6 
makeFlOW <- d_flow[d_flow$name_change==1,]
mean(makeFlOW$lag_median_flow) 
mean(makeFlOW$lead_median_flow, na.rm = TRUE)

# TNA Median +6 -6 
makeTNA <- d_TNA[d_TNA$name_change==1,]
mean(makeTNA$lag_median_TNA) 
mean(makeTNA$lead_median_TNA, na.rm = TRUE)

# Return Mean +6 -6 
makeRETURN_mean <- d_m[d_m$name_change==1,]
mean(makeRETURN_mean$lag_mean) 
mean(makeRETURN_mean$lead_mean, na.rm = TRUE)

# Flow Mean +6 -6 
makeFLOW_mean <- d_flow_mean[d_flow$name_change==1,]
mean(makeFLOW_mean$lag_mean_flow)            
mean(makeFLOW_mean$lead_mean_flow, na.rm = TRUE)

# TNA Mean +6 -6 
makeTNA_mean <- d_tna_mean[d_TNA$name_change==1,]
mean(makeTNA_mean$lag_mean_tna) 
mean(makeTNA_mean$lead_mean_tna, na.rm = TRUE)


library(stargazer)
#how to display a matrix with Return -- Mean - Median for +6 -6 ? 
stargazer(makeTNA_mean, makeFLOW_mean, makeRETURN_mean, makeTNA, makeFlOW, makeRETURN, type = "text")
```

The stargazer part at the end doesn't work.

highly apreciate any help!

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: The usual caveat: you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘[modelsummary](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modelsummary)’ or ‘[texreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=texreg)’ instead, or *literally anything else*.

Comment: Or `kableExtra`

Comment: Thanks Konrad! appreciate the quick feedback. I'll look into that. And thanks for hinting that stargazer is not good at all.