# This code gives me an error: Error in if (is.na(s)) { : the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, if-statement, stargazer

Please help resolve this error that I get when I execute the following:

```
stargazer(as.data.frame(st_sect.hh.earnings[st_sect.hh.earnings$sector.f=="Rural",c(1,3,4)]), 
      type="html", 
      title="Mean and Standard Deviation of Monthly Household Income by State for Rural India (Unweighted)", 
      summary=F, covariate.labels=c("S.No.", "State", "Mean", "Std.Dev."), 
      digits=0,
      notes=c("Source: Periodic Labour Force Survey, 2017-18"), 
      out=c("tb2.state-rural.hh.earnings.html"))
```

Comment: Can you isolate the error? Is it in your subset code, does `st_sect.hh.earnings[st_sect.hh.earnings$sector.f=="Rural",c(1,3,4)]` work? If that works, is it in the data frame conversion, does `as.data.frame(st_sect.hh.earnings[st_sect.hh.earnings$sector.f=="Rural",c(1,3,4)])` work? If that works, then it must be in the `stargazer()` call. In that case, can does it work on the first 5 rows of data? Can you find a small subset of data that demonstrates the problem? And then share it in the question?

Comment: No in both the cases, with or without the dataframe conversion, I'm getting the same error. I'm new to R.. I don't know how to obtain a smaller subset of the data that I'm using. Although I googled this issue and several people in reddit have mentioned that it is a stargazer package problem. It works when we assign it to an object

Comment: Define `df = as.data.frame(st_sect.hh.earnings[st_sect.hh.earnings$sector.f=="Rural",c(1,3,4)]` and then run `dput(df)` and put the results in the question. That will give us a copy/pasteable version of your data including in all class and structure information.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem. For me, it helped to define the data frame outside of the stargazer function.
So it would be

```
df <- as.data.frame(st_sect.hh.earnings[st_sect.hh.earnings$sector.f=="Rural",c(1,3,4)])
stargazer(df, 
      type="html", 
      title="Mean and Standard Deviation of Monthly Household Income by State for Rural India (Unweighted)", 
      summary=F, covariate.labels=c("S.No.", "State", "Mean", "Std.Dev."), 
      digits=0,
      notes=c("Source: Periodic Labour Force Survey, 2017-18"), 
      out=c("tb2.state-rural.hh.earnings.html"))
```

Edit (after the discussion in the comments): The reason for this is that the argument input length should not be too long. Check the comments below.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried something similar when I had a bunch of fit models from regressions that were giving me this error.  I put them all into a list first, then fed that list as the first argument in the stargazer function and it solved the error.

Comment: This is so weird. Defining the DF outside the function fixed my problem, too. Why on earth would this matter?

Comment: That is a good question. Others had similar problems. It was also discussed observed [here][1] and [here][2] and according to [AK][3], it might have todo with the fact that the input-length of this argument is too long. 

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436661/im-getting-error-in-if-is-nas-the-condition-has-length-1-on-a-starg
[2]:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72230474/summary-of-descriptive-data
[3]:  https://twitter.com/Alex_Knorre/status/1531514507402563585

Comment: PS: I just logged in on Twitter and found out that in his comments, there is a great of why this happens. Check it out: https://twitter.com/Alex_Knorre/status/1531514507402563585. "The error happens inside the internal function to extract models' names. It first checks if object s is n/a, and only after this for its length." There shouldn't be more than 60 chars.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but maybe a hint: the following code

```
library(functional)
library(stargazer)

tabify <- function(models){

sgCurried = Curry(stargazer)

do.call(sgCurried, models)
}


mydf <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(15), Z = ceiling(rnorm(15)))

regr <- lm(Y ~ Z, data=mydf)

models = list(regr)

tabify(models)
```

... used to work with R 4.1.2, while it fails with R 4.2.2, (stargazer is 5.2.3 in both cases), producing the error reported by the OP.